# Force Close always occuring on android device (even with very simple hello world code)

Tags: android, debugging, monodevelop, xamarin.android

My university recently got monodroid working in the labs and I've spent the day trying to get to grips with it.

However, upon building the basic tutorial scripts to an actual phone (desire hd and incredible s) they will instantly bring up a force close message.

[EDIT] Ok here goes. This is (in my view), an extremely simple procedure based on the initial monoDevelopProject.

I've left out using the namespace sections for clarity, these are all left default.

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);

    // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

    // Get our button from the layout resource,
    // and attach an event to it
    Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);
    // on button click change button text
    button.Click += delegate { button.Text = string.Format("You clicked the button!") };
}
```

So, this compiles, builds and runs with no errors on a standard sdk 2.3 emu. But not on an actual device.

I am unable to retrieve any debugging information from the device (I've followed the instructions to allow wifi debugging). With a break point included at line 3 above (`base.onCreate(bundle);`) it appears to not even step into this method and simply stops the debug after the force close.

I will try and debug this again from the device and get some more details now. I may have gotten something wrong.

I have just tried a few example projects from the xamarin gitHub, ranging from simple layouts to full 3d oGL examples and all return a force close messages upon running on my device. I will look into some of the compiler settings and do a reboot of this system

When I run the debug (green arrow), it doesn't even enable the pause/stop buttons (like it should and does on the emu). Genuinely no idea what's wrong, it's as if the app is being killed as soon as its sent to the device. I have a feeling it's not been installed correctly on these systems as I've tried two computers in the lab now.

Comment: Can you post debugging output logs for the crash?

Comment: It's hard to debug something you can't see :) I suggest [edit]ing this to include as simple a reproducer as you can build and as detailed error messages as you can get. (Paying special attention to compiler warnings.)

Comment: Could you try removing your breakpoints ? This "force close" dialog is shown when Android detects the application is not responding - which is the case when the debugger is waiting on a breakpoint. Maybe MonoDevelop does not show the breakpoint (or the wrong file) so you could try without breakpoints or use "Run" to continue the execution and see if it *solves* the issue.

Comment: I see, however the problem remains with no breakpoints, physically I can see the application title shown for a second before the force close, so it appears to set up and start running but crash as or just before the Activity1 class is stepped into.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear. It's not only break**points** it's *general* break - i.e. when the debugger stop (break) the execution then Android will *suspect* the app is frozen and can show you this "force close" dialog. If you can step / resume (run) from MonoDevelop then it should (from memory) be dismissed automatically (i.e. you do not have to answer the dialog).

Comment: Ah, I understand. Would there be any reason as to why when I start the debug it doesn't bring up the [play, stop pause] buttons? I fear I am doing the completely wrong thing when I hit f5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to jpobst's answer I'd recommend you get a log viewer for your device and watch it while your app is running. I have no affiliation with these guys but I have found myself using their app again and again. https://market.android.com/details?id=com.nolanlawson.logcat&hl=en

Comment: thank you, it appears i was right in thinking it wasnt installed correctly. using catLog i found the error "ERROR: This version of MonoDroid will only run in the Android Emulator." I'll talk to tech support and get them to check the install.

Comment: When in doubt catlog seems to help out. Np.

Answer (score 3):

Try running it without debugging (Ctrl-F5), let it crash, and then check the debug log for the exception causing the crash:

http://docs.xamarin.com/android/advanced_topics/android_debug_log

Answer (score 0):

OP says that they have solved the problem:

> MonoDroid was not installed correctly in the labs, even though all information pointing to registration/authentication stated otherwise.